# wlan0 - b43 - not being recognized (model - BCM4311)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, wifi-driver, broadcom

wlan0 - b43 - not being recognized (model - Broadcom BCM4311)

Here's the output after running `wifi-menu`:

```
n180211: Could not set interface'wlan0' UP
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): No such device
WEXT: Could not set interface'wlan0' UP
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

Here's me trying to run `ip link set wlan0 UP`:

```
Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "UP is a garbage"
```

`ip link show` output for wlan0:

```
wlan0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

Measures taken: 

1. Reloading the modules with `rmmod b43` then `modprobe b43`. 
 
2. Deleting `/lib/firmware/b43` re-downloading `broadcom-wl` and reinstalling b43 from scratch with `b43-fwcutter -w` inside the `/usr/lib/firmware/` folder.


Here's the `dmesg` output:

```
[    8.338235] systemd-journald[142]: File /var/log/journal/a03a9102551b4394ab4bd1a237770fa5/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   20.724653] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 10)
[   20.760062] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 4, Type 2 (G), Revision 8
[   20.760087] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2050, Revision 2, Version 0
[   20.760090] b43-phy0 warning: 5 GHz band is unsupported on this PHY
[   20.834639] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   20.834686] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   20.834735] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   20.834769] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode5.fw failed with error -2
[   20.834776] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[   20.834931] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found
[   20.835076] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   85.300501] systemd-journald[142]: File /var/log/journal/a03a9102551b4394ab4bd1a237770fa5/user-1005.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
```

**Update:**

I managed to get it working, but only temporarily. The drivers were installed inside of `/lib/firmware/b43/b43`instead of `/lib/firmware/b43/`.

The device is indeed recognized by iw and ip link 9. So there must be a problem with how it is interfacing with these other linux services that handle network devices. I am not an expert in Linux so I don't know where to go to correct the problem.

Now, upon using wifi-menu, I am returned with the following error output:

```
b43-phy2 ERROR: Microcode not responding.
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP) : No such device
nl80211: could not set interface wlan0 UP
 WEXT: Could not set interface wlan0 UP
wlan0: failed to initialize driver interface
failed
```

ip link shows the device is there (and is indeed DOWN), and systemctl shows the bcm4311 modules are loaded and running. I tried ip link wlan0 up and got an identical message. I tried deleting and reinstalling the b43 folder with `b43-fwcutter broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o` and running  `modprobe b43` then `ip link set wlan0 up`. Same result.

Comment: What’s the `dmesg` output when you do `modprobe b43` (when not having the module loaded, of course)?

Comment: I've posted the `dmesg` output for my b43 installation problem. Would you mind taking a look and giving further guidance? Thanks!

Comment: So it’s a firmware problem. What are the contents of `/lib/firmware/b43` and `/lib/firmware/b43-open`? How did you call the `b43-fwcutter` tool?

Comment: i managed to get it working, but only temporarily. the drivers were installed inside of `/lib/firmware/b43/b43` instead of `/lib/firmware/b43/`. There is no `b43-open.`

Comment: Now, upon using `wifi-menu,` I am returned with the following error output: `b43-phy2  ERROR: Microcode not responding.` <br> `Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP) : No such device`<br> `nl80211: could not set interface wlan0 UP`<br> `WEXT: Could not set interface wlan0 UP`<br> `wlan0: failed to initialize driver interface`<br> `failed`

Comment: ip link shows the device is there (and is indeed DOWN), and systemctl shows the bcm4311 modules are loaded and running. I tried `ip link wlan0 up` and got an identical message. I tried deleting and reinstalling the b43 folder and running `rmmod b43` and `modprobe b43` then `ip link set wlan0 up.` Same result.

Comment: This all happened after having successfully connected to wifi once, then shut down. I started up and tried connecting again and got this message.

Comment: The `dmesg` isn't showing any missing driver files, but it does repeat the `microcode not responding`

Comment: Is there an `iw` command i can run to get this up and running? I've been trying to solve this problem for 18 days now.

Comment: Any tools you use can’t do anything if the firmware isn’t working correctly. I can’t provide specific help on this adapter. You might want to get a different one that is guaranteed to work with Linux.

Comment: Well this one has been working fine for two years, then, after a routine scan with airodump-ng, out of the blue it stops working.

Comment: The device is indeed recognized by iw and ip link. So there must be a problem with how it is interfacing with these other linux services that handle network devices. I am not an expert in Linux so I don't know where to go to correct the problem.

Comment: Did you upgrade anything? For example the driver, or the firmware? Firmware problems are really something that should be resolved by the developers, so file a bug at the website of the driver, and/or ask on the mailinglist for the driver.

Comment: i didn't update anything. i did use airmon-ng. Perhaps that fiddled with a name or some switch? Though that was some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

From the Arch Wiki: BCM4306 rev.3, **BCM4311**, BCM4312 noticed to have problems with b43-firmware. Use `b43-firmware-classic` for these cards instead.

Use `b43` together with `b43-firmware-classic`. Also, `b43` and `wl` are different drivers - you can use only one or the other.

If you delete `broadcom-wl` or `broadcom-wl-dkms` and `b43-firmware` from your computer and reinstall `b43` after purging stale configs, WLAN should work.

Comment: I dont have bcm4311, i have 14e4:4312 with the 4311 chipset. I've since uninstalled arch and installed debian. I am having a similar problem. dmesg reports that the modules are loading, lsmod and iwconfig and ip link are showing the device and the drivers, but when i try to do ip link set wlan0 up, i get RTNETLINK device not found.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1190641/453189